# h5py.File(path) doesn't recognize folder path

Tags: python, path, jupyter-notebook, load, h5py

I am in my project folder call "project". I have two neural network h5 file, one in "project/my_folder/my_model_1.h5", I also copy it to folder "project/my_model_2.h5". So I open my Jupyter Notebook which is working at "project" folder.

```
import h5py
f = h5py.File("my_model_2.h5") # has NO Issue
```

but

```
f = h5py.File("my_folder/my_model_1.h5") # OSError
```

It says `OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'my_folder/my_model_1.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)`

Interestingly, I only have this issue when I do the same thing on my Mac, but I don't encounter any issue in Linux machine.

Please let me know if you know how to fix this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `h5py.File("./my_folder/my_model_1.h5")`? The added`'./'` is the current folder/directory.

Comment: @kcw78 I just tried, and it still doesn't work

Comment: What happens if you check with `assert os.path.isfile("my_folder/my_model_1.h5")`?

Comment: @titusjan AssertionError: 
No other info following the the AssertionError. And I specifically check the current working directory using `os.getcwd()`, I'm sure the folder and file are there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like some hidden invalid character incidentally got copied when I simply copy and paste the file path from Mac folder system. Take a look at the code in the screen.
[image]

The Line 92 is the path name I directly copy and paste from Mac folder.

The Line 93 is the path I literally type with every single letter, then there is no error and .h5 file is loaded properly. It's a kinda of similar issue that has been spotted by someone at this link: [Invalid character in identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14844687/invalid-character-in-identifier)

I simply copy the error code to Pycharm, and the unwelcome character got busted.

[image]

So solution, for Mac user, be careful of of just simply copying the text from folder system, if something obviously weird, try type every letter into the text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the absolute path using the os worked in windows

```
file_name = os.path.dirname(__file__) +'\\my_folder\\my_model_1.h5'
f = h5py.File(file_name)
```

dont forget to import os though